# AJAX added options not shown in select in Firefox

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, laravel, firefox

A `<select>` element is being updated with an ajax call, but when data are retrieved and added to DOM Firefox doesn't show all `<option>` elements.

Inspecting the page, all elements result as correctly added, but the browser doesn't show neither allow scroll to elements after the 10th.

**This is happening only on Firefox** (my version is 83.0).
[image: What happens in Firefox]

Chrome (86.0.4240.198) and Safari (13.0.1) both have the desired, normal behavior.
[image: What happens in Safari and Chrome]

This is the code in Laravel's (8) blade view:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="regione" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Regione</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <select id="regione" name="regione" class="form-control @error('regione') is-invalid @enderror">
           <option value="" selected></option>
       </select>
       @error('regione')
           <span class="text-danger" role="alert">
               <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
           </span>
       @enderror
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the Ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/excavations/getAjaxData',
    data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "tipoRichiesta": "listaRegioni",
        "parametri": ""
    },
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
})
.done(function(risultato){
    switch(risultato.successo){
        case true:
            // Aggiorno la lista delle regioni
            var listaOptions = "<option value=''></option>";
            risultato.dati.forEach(function(regione,idx,array){
                listaOptions += "<option value='"+regione.codRegione+"'>"+regione.regione+"</option>";
            });
            // Compila la lista regioni nella rispettiva Select
            $("#regione").html(listaOptions)
            break;
        case false:
            $("#regione").html("<option value=''></option>")
            break;
    }
})
```

Data are retrieved from a Laravel model and composed into a JSON object like this: `{"successo":true,"dati":[{"codRegione":1,"regione":"Piemonte"},...other regions...]}`

This is the Ajax request as from the Console:
[image: Ajax request]

PS: as a secondary issue, I can't correctly render the string "Trentino-Alto Adige/Südtirol" because of the "ü" char...

Comment: Could you please share request AJAX in `network` tab (F12)?

Comment: Edited the post. As you can see it returns 200 code.

Comment: First, is there any error in `console` tab? Second, you use `console.log(risultato);` after `.done(function(risultato){`. Could you please share output of `console.log`?

Comment: No errors.
The "risultato" content: {"successo":true,"dati":[{"codRegione":1,"regione":"Piemonte"},{"codRegione":2,"regione":"Valle d'Aosta"},{"codRegione":3,"regione":"Lombardia"}, ... ELEMENTS OMITTED DUE TO STACKOVERFLOW CHAR LIMIT IN COMMENTS ...,{"codRegione":18,"regione":"Calabria"},{"codRegione":19,"regione":"Sicilia"},{"codRegione":20,"regione":"Sardegna"}]}

Comment: I think that version Firefox `83.0` does not support. You could set manually a scroll bar for `select` tag. Do you think about this?

Comment: Can you post a link to a test-case that reproduces the issue?